# Result from stored procedure using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate, stored-procedures, jpa, ejb

I'm trying to retrieve the result from a stored procedure by using Hibernate in an EJB stateless session bean.

The stored procedure is running on MS SQL Server 2008 and takes an integer as parameter and returns another integer.

I managed to call the procedure using

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("name_of_my_procedure :param");
q.setParameter("param", sequence);
q.executeUpdate().
```

Using getResultList or getSingleResult instead of executeUpdate, always results in a funny exception.

In EJB 3.0 in Action I found this :

*JPA doesn’t support stored procedures, and you have to depend on a proprietary feature of your persistence provider*

I found a few posts speaking about using CallableStatement through a SQL Connection but this solution looks pretty inappropriate.

Is there a way to retrieve my generated id using Hibernate?

Thank you.

Fred.

Comment: its all simple if you can you use a function instead of a stored procedure.Can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I fixed it using another stored procedure.

I created a new stored procedure to call the other one and store the results in a temporary table. 
I mapped an entity on this temporary table and I can now retrieve the information I need.

I know it's not the most elegant way to do it, but I didn't want to mix/use SQL connection code with JPA code.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question as such, but FYI JPA 2.1 supports (or will support, when released) a [stored procedure API](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/stored_procedures.html). The only JPA implementation that provides this AFAIK is DataNucleus JPA.

Comment: I already had a look here :

https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft

It looks pretty interesting and it would fit my needs but in the mean time I need a solution using JPA 2.0.

What about TopLink? Doesn't it also support calls to stored procedures?